# SQLServer 2012 SP1 Standard Edition Install on Windows 2007 SP2 Standard - Install Successful, Visual Studio 2010 reuires reinstall

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, sql-server-2012

I installed SQL 2012 SP1 Standard edition today. The installation completed successfully but I see a visual studio 2010 shell reinstall required message. Per google results, we need to install and reinstall VS 2010 and then SQL 2012. Not sure when SQLServer uses Visual Studio, this is aplain vanilla install.

Please advise if you have encountered this error and your recommendation.

Here are the details. Thank you very much for your help.

After Install, I received the following message -

1. Your SQLserver 2012 Installation completed successfully with product updates. All features show a status of successful. Features selected : Management tools - completed, Client Tools connectivity, Client tools SDK, Client tools backward compatibility, Management tools - basic, Database engine services, Integration services. ( all with status Succeeded)

Then a message -
Computer restart required - One or more affected files have operations pending. You must restart your computer after the setup process is completed.

1. When I close setup, I see the following popup - Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell - Invalid license data. reinstall is required.

I checked my install summary.txt file and the error files. There are no errors. Install is successful and only information messages in the error log files.

I was able to use SSMS and login successful.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Log details -Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Passed but reboot required, see logs for details
  Exit code (Decimal):           3010
  Start time:                    2014-05-26 06:25:21
  End time:                      2014-05-26 06:53:48
  Requested action:              Install

Comment: Detailed results:
Feature:  Management Tools - Complete
Status:   Passed
Feature:  Client Tools Connectivity
Status:   Passed
Feature:  Client Tools SDK
Status:   Passed
Feature:  Client Tools Backwards Compatibility
Status:   Passed
Feature:  Management Tools - Basic
Status:   Passed
Feature:  Database Engine Services
Status:   Passed
Feature:  Integration Services
Status:   Passed

Comment: Yes, restarted server. Instance is up.